# Active Directory sssd not Updating DNS

Tags: windows-server-2016, sssd, debian-stretch

I have been migrating my Vm lab over to AD to centralize the auth management and im having issue with the linux VM's (Debian 8) not updating DNS records.

the clients are being joined with realmd and after joining, I can auth with the domain accounts.

my sssd.conf file:

```
[sssd]
domains = domain.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/domain.local]
ad_domain = domain.local
krb5_realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad

debug_level = 5
```

the sssdd log file:

```
(Sun Oct 14 22:47:54 2018) [sssd[be[domain.local]]] [nsupdate_child_timeout] (0x0020): Timeout reached for dynamic DNS update
(Sun Oct 14 22:47:54 2018) [sssd[be[domain.local]]] [be_nsupdate_done] (0x0040): nsupdate child execution failed [1432158239]: Dynamic DNS update timed out
(Sun Oct 14 22:47:54 2018) [sssd[be[domain.local]]] [ad_dyndns_sdap_update_done] (0x0040): Dynamic DNS update failed [1432158239]: Dynamic DNS update timed out
(Sun Oct 14 22:47:54 2018) [sssd[be[domain.local]]] [ad_dyndns_nsupdate_done] (0x0040): Updating DNS entry failed [1432158239]: Dynamic DNS update timed out
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   server.domain.local server localhost
```

I'm not sure at this point what else to check so any direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

turns out this was a bug in 1.15.0 of sssd and updating sssd solved it, in my case i had to get the package from debian testing.